# Distinguish between a log file and a file logged in the log file

Tags: forms, wording

This form has a file upload element which is used to upload a log file, and a drop down to select files that are 'logged' in the log file. The users of this will be familiar with what a log file is and the structure of the specific log files used in this tool. My questions is: Do the labels accurately describe what the elements are for? If they don't, how could they be better described?

[image: Wording of form elements]

Comment: I thought I knew the difference from the question, but then I saw what you were trying to do and now I honestly don't know what your selector is selecting. Let's say I upload a file, octopus.log. Will that file show up in the list? I'm thinking it won't. So,  what will show up? And what does selecting it do?

Answer (score 1):

The controls are fine. Clarity in the wording would be an improvement.

- First, upload your log
- Then, select the [relevant] file within your log

Only allow step two after step one has been completed.